# Identify consecutive block of Hexadecimal characters in a Javascript string

Tags: javascript

In javascript i want to determine if a string is composed only of Hexadecimal characters or not. i.e., it i want to check if the string is a consecutive block of characters in the range `a-f, A-F, 0-9`. How can i do this in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

`/^[a-f0-9]+$/i.test("ABCDEF")`

Or

```
var r = new RegExp("^[a-f0-9]+$", 'i')
r.test("ABCDEF");
```

Comment: How can i test a consecutive block

Comment: The code exactly does that.. Do you have any specific questions?